# Mapping some URLS with Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsp, jstl

Hi there im new with spring boot and mvc model im trying to create some methods to call some data to the Mongo D.B using postman im getting the data but now i want to show this data in a web page but i cant figure out how mapping works in spring boot.
I have this methods:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Informacion")
public class InformacionControlador {
@Autowired
private informacionRepo informacioRepo;

public InformacionControlador(informacionRepo informacioRepo) {
    this.informacioRepo = informacioRepo;
}

//This method is comment because using postman get the answer in json format

//    @GetMapping("/Listar")
//    public List<Informacion> getAll() {
//        List<Informacion> info = this.informacioRepo.findAll();
//        return info;
//    }

//Now this is the method that i want to work like the first one but 
//instead of json answer y want to see the data in ListarInformacion page

@GetMapping("/Listar")
public String informacion(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("info", informacioRepo.findAll());
    return "ListarInformacion";
}


@PutMapping
public void insert(@RequestBody Informacion informacion) {
    this.informacioRepo.insert(informacion);
}

}
```

Also i put this lines in application.properties file to set the folder where the page will be storage

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/webapp/Vistas
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is my ListarInformacion page

```
<html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="GET" action="/webapp/Vistas/ListarInformacion" modelAttribute="Informacion">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
     <thead class="thead-dark">
     <tr>
         <th scope="col">ID</th>
         <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">Identificación</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha Creación</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<c:forEach var="p" items="${info}">
    <tr>
        <td>${p.idInformacion}</td>
        <td>${p.nombre}</td>
        <td>${p.pais}</td>
        <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${p.fechaCreacion}"/></td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

[this is the location of my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHLN4.png)

can anyone tell me what am i missin because when i try to access to the url localhost:8080/Informacion/Listar the answer is a String that says /ListarInformacion ant its no redirecting me to the page that its supose to redirect

Answer (score 0):

You should try to access `localhost:8080/Informacion/Listar` as you have already given mapping to the controller class (`/Informacion`)

the preferred location to put the jsp in a spring boot project is

```
--webapp
       --WEB-INF
         --jsp
           --your.jsp
```

in your case it is 
   -

```
-webapp
       --WEB-INF(Create WEB-INF directory if you don't have)
            --Vistas(folder)
         --jsp
           --hello.jsp
```

And your view path in properties file will be  `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/Vistas`

Comment: my mistake sorry, i actually try the same url localhost:8080/Informacion/Listar but still getting the same string but not get the page :/

Comment: change this `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/webapp/Vistas/` add / in the end @BryanSaltos

Comment: i add / at the end now im getting this error :
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not resolve view with name 'ListarInformacion' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

and in the console :

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'ListarInformacion' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: where is your WEB-INF folder??

Comment: sorry for the late answer had some problems btw this is all my files

Comment: share your pom.xml please @BryanSaltos

Comment: sorry for late answer but i already change the entire code .. some much bugs so i started it again :)